# Akka equivalent of Spring InitializingBean

Tags: akka

I have written some actor classes and I find that I have to get a handle into the lifecycle of these entities. For example whenever my actor is initialized I would like a method to be called so that I can setup some listeners on message queues (or open db connections etc).

Is there an equivalent of this? The equivalent I can think of is Spring's InitialisingBean and DisposableBean

Comment: I do see methods like preStart() etc but I don't seem to get a call back on these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical scenario where you would [override methods](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.4/akka/actor/Actor.html) like `preStart()`, `postStop()`, etc. I don't see anything wrong with this.

Of course you have to be aware of the details - for example `postStop()` is called asynchronously after `actor.stop()` is invoked while `preStart()` is called when an Actor is started. This means that potentially slow/blocking things like DB interaction should be kept to a minimum.

You can also use the Actor's constructor for initialization of data.

As Matthew mentioned, supervision plays a big part in Akka - so you can instruct the supervisor to perform specific stuff on events. For example the so-called *[DeathWatch](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#Lifecycle_Monitoring_aka_DeathWatch)* - you can be notified if one of the actors "you are watching upon" dies:

```
context.watch(child)

...

def receive = {
    case Terminated(`child`) => lastSender ! "finished"
}
```

Comment: postStop may be a valuable callback because of its lifecycle (it's more reliable than a finalize method for cleaning up resources). preStart, being called by the actor system directly after instantiation, has basically the same lifecycle as the constructor.

Comment: True but there is another point. In the default implementation of `postRestart` the `preStart` is called - so one can also override `postRestart` and then skip the second call to `preStart` or call it under some condition. But this is really a corner case.

Comment: One I'd prefer to see covered by improved design :). But that's cool

Answer (score 1):

An Actor is basically two methods -- a constructor, and `onMessage(Object): void`.

There's nothing in its lifecycle that naturally provides for "wiring" behavior, which leaves you with a few options.

1. **Use a Supervisor actor to create your other actors**. A Supervisor is responsible for watching, starting and restarting Actors on failure -- and therefore it is often valuable to have a Supervisor that understands the state of integrated systems to avoid continously restarting. This Supervisor would create and manage Service objects (possibly via Spring) and pass them to Actors.
2. **Use your preferred Initialization technique at the time of Actor construction.** It's tricky but you can certainly combine Spring with Actors. Just be aware that should a Supervisor restart your actor, you'll need to be able to resurrect its desired state from whatever content you placed in the Props object you used to start it in the first place.
3. **Wire everything on-demand**. Open connections on demand when an Actor starts (and cache them as necessary). I find I do this fairly often -- and I let the Actor fail when its connections no longer work. The supervisor will restart the Actor, which will recreate all connections.

Something important things to remember:

- The intent of Actor model is that Actors don't run continuously -- they only run when there are messages provided to them. If you add a message listener to an Actor, you are essentially adding new threads that can access that actor. This can be a problem if you use supervision -- a restarted actor may leak that thread and this may in turn cause the actor not to be garbage collected. It can also be a problem because it introduces a race condition, and part of the value of actors is avoiding that.
- An Actor that does I/O is, from the perspective of the actor system, blocking. If you have too many Actors doing I/O at the same time, you will exhaust your Dispatcher's thread pool and lock up the system.
- A given Actor instance can operate on many different threads over its lifetime, but will only operate on one thread at a time. This can be confusing to some messaging systems -- for example, JMS' Spec asserts that a Session not be used on multiple threads, and many JMS interpret this as "can only run on the thread on which it was started." You may see warnings, or even exceptions, resulting from this.
- For these reasons, I prefer to use non-actor code to do some of my I/O. For example, I'll have an incoming message listener object whose responsibility is to take JMS messages off a queue, use them to create POJO messages, and send tells to the Actor system. Alternately, I'll use an Actor, but place that actor on a custom Dispatcher that has thread pinning enabled. This assures that that Actor will only run on a specific thread and won't block up the system that other non-I/O actors are using.